# Powershell problems at value adding for the search loop

Tags: powershell

So I got here something that I cant explain better.

```
$var = "Admin_Group"
Get-ADGroupMembers $var
```

Works fine, now the issue that is itching me for some time...

```
$get_AD_Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | Select-Object Name
foreach ($item in $get_AD_Groups) {

$get_users = Get-ADGroupMember "$item"| Select-Object Name

}
```

Now the `Get-ADGroupMember` in `foreach(...)` loop is giving me error that the same given string as on top example does not exist

Error:

> Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '@{Name=Admin_Group}'

Already tried it with '' and with "". Help, thanks :)

Comment: You need to expand the property. Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` or, use it in your loop, `$item.name`

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember "$item"` -> `Get-ADGroupMember $item.Name`

Comment: Got the same problem. C# does this a bit the other way around :/

Answer (score 0):

So what i found out, and its working it that instead of

```
Get-ADGroupMember "$item"| Select-Object Name
```

i use `$get_users =  $item.Name | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object Name`

Dont know if this makes sense but it works.